# what approach is better when searching for values in mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a mysql db with phonenumbers, however I can't edit the database...

I have a php form that makes the connections and ask if a number exist and if it does it will reply with 1/0 (yes/no).

However... some phonenumbers that I know existing won't appear, and I found out that some numbers contains spaces randomly in the phonenumber...

How can I improve my mysql query or should I just take down all the numbers, replace all spaces and put them in array and then compare to my value via loop throught?

Examples of what every single cell contains...

```
070 00 000 00
0700 0000 00
070 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 700000000
```

Comment: *How can I improve my mysql query* Should we guess it ? How can we improve something you keep secret?

Comment: Is this a real problem or just a homework question? The right solution for one is the wrong solution for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the spaces, both from the stored and requested phone number, and compare them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE REPLACE(phone, ' ', '') = <Requested-Phone-Number-Without-Spaces>
```

Comment: This is, unfortunately, an extremely intensive process. You'll notice the speed with a fairly small amount of numbers. @op you say you can't edit the database, I'd certainly recommend it, though. Even if it just means adding a new column with the spaceless numbers.